# Symfony form error: Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\User" given at property path

Tags: symfony

```
$builder
    ->add('ophaal_locatie')
    ->add('lesdoel')
    ->add('naam_leerling')
    ->add('naam_instructeur', null, [
        'data' => $user->getEmail(),
        'label' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'my-custom-class',
            'style' => 'display: none;',
        ],
    ])

    ->add('datum')
    ->add('prijs')
    ->add('Leerling', 'NonexistentClass', [
        'class' => User::class, 
        'choice_label' => 'username', field
    ]);
```

> I'm working on a Symfony form and encountering an error. The error message is: "Expected argument of type 'string', 'App\Entity\User' given at property path 'naam_instructeur'." I'm trying to set the default value of the 'naam_instructeur' field to the email of the logged-in user.
>
> Here's the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

> Hey,NinjaCoder69 try this:

```
use App\Entity\Lessen;
use Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class LessenType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();



        $builder
            // STATUS EERST OPTIONEEL MAKEN IN DB (Als het staat op tecnhnisch ontwerp docenten)
//            ->add('status', null, [
//                'empty_data' => "\xC2\xA0",
//            ])

            ->add('ophaal_locatie')
            ->add('lesdoel')
            ->add('naam_leerling')
            ->add('naam_instructeur', null, [
                'data' => $user->getEmail(),
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'my-custom-class',
                    'style' => 'display: none;',
                ],
            ])

            ->add('datum')
            ->add('prijs')
            ->add('Leerling', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class, 
                'choice_label' => 'username', 
            ])
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->add('Leerling', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class, 
    'choice_label' => 'username', 
])
```